# When accessing a class variable updated in a method, its updated value is not picked up in another method in scrapy spider

Tags: python, class, scrapy

I am trying to parse a public forum that contains multiple threads. I need to store metadata of that thread. These metadata appear before getting inside the thread i.e in the page which displays the list of discussion threads.

In my *scrapy* code below, I need to access values from `parse()` method in `parse_contents()` method. I am storing those values in class variables but the `parse_contents()` picks up the first value that was assigned the very first time although the new value has been assigned before calling `parse_contents()`.

Here is my spider class

```
import scrapy
import re
import pandas as pd
import time
from functools import reduce
from ..items import PostsItem

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'posts'

    page_count = 1
    forum_count = 0

    #Create an item container to store all this data
    post_item = PostsItem()
    
    # I want these variables to parse_contents() method
    post_subject_last_message_date = ""
    total_posts = 0

    start_urls = [
        # 'https://www.dcurbanmom.com/jforum/posts/list/150/946237.page'
        'https://www.dcurbanmom.com/jforum/forums/show/32.page'
    ]

    # Grabs the list of threads in the DCPS forum
    def parse(self, response):

        for next_forum in response.xpath('//span[@class="topictitle"]'):

            next_forum_link = next_forum.xpath('.//a/@href')
            next_forum_url = response.urljoin(next_forum_link.extract_first())

            last_message = next_forum.xpath('.//ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[4]/span/text()')
            self.post_subject_last_message_date = last_message.get() #This needs to be picked up by parse_contents 

            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_forum_url, callback=self.parse_contents)

        #Get next page of duscussion threads list
        #Some code here
                      
    #Parses individual discussion thread
    def parse_contents(self, response):
        all_posts = response.xpath('//table[@class="forumline"]//tr')
        post_text = ""

        for post in all_posts:

            post_text_response = post.xpath(".//div[@class='postbody']/br/following-sibling::text()[1] | .//div[@class='postbody']/br/following-sibling::a[1]/text() | .//div[@class='postbody']/text() | .//div[@class='postbody']/a/text()")
            if(len(post_text_response.getall())>0):
                post_text = "".join(re.sub('\r','',x) for x in post_text_response.getall()).strip()
            #Populate the item container
            if(bool(re.search(r'^\s*$', post_text))==False):
                self.post_item['post_message'] = post_text

                # !!! This is not picking up the value updated in the parse method !!! 
                self.post_item['post_subject_last_message_date'] = self.post_subject_last_message_date

                post_text = ""

                yield(self.post_item)  

        # Go to next page in this discussion thread
        # Some code here
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: removed some lines of code to make it easier to read

Comment: Uh, this is very complex. Can you please try to reduce it to a [mre]?

Comment: @tripleee I have removed some lines of code to make is easier to read. Also, I have added comments that tell which variables I want to pass between methods and store in item

Comment: Storing stateful metadata about a particular instance as class variables seems misdirected and wrong on several levels. You should create an instance of your class and store information about this instance as attributes of that instance instead. Class variables should contain information about the class itself (something which is true at the same time for all instances of the class, no matter how many there are).

Comment: @tripleee Can you give an example as to how I can get around this? I am not required to create an instance of this class separately. To run this spider I simply enter `scrapy crawl posts` on terminal. I am not sure how I can pass the values between methods inside the spider class itself

Comment: "Not required to" doesn't mean it's not a good idea. Create an `__init__` method and replace the class variables with attributes on `self`.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the suggestion. I will incorporate that coding habit in my current and future codes

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question; please roll back your latest edit - probably post it as an answer instead, and (eventually) mark it as accepted.

Comment: @tripleee Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `yield scrapy.Request(url = next_forum_url, callback=self.parse_contents)` with the following fixed it for me

```
yield scrapy.Request(url = next_forum_url, callback=self.parse_contents, cb_kwargs = {
                'post_subject_answers': post_subject_answer,
                'post_subject_first_post_date':post_subject_first_post_date,
                'post_subject_views':post_subject_views,
                'post_subject_last_message_date':post_subject_last_message_date
            })
```